# Microsoft Azure Media Service. Unable to get token (app-only) by using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-api-apps

I'm building simple Angular2 application where a given user can upload videos via Microsoft Azure Media Service REST API.

I'm trying to get a token by using this request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://rest.media.azure.net/&client_id=<application id>&client_secret=<password you selected for authentication>" https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Azure AD Tenant ID>/oauth2/token?api-version=2.11
```

But it will not work via AJAX (that's because CORS), so is there any other simple way to get an app-only token?

Comment: Most modern browsers will block that type of call due to CORS.  You will need to build a middle tier API that your AJAX can call and that trusts your web application via CORS setup on the API.  Suggest you look at using Azure API Management or Azure Functions as the host for your custom logic.  This is also a good idea for securing your service principal credentials used to call your Media Services application.

Comment: Thanks @johndeu I guess it will be fastest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created php script which returns token, I think it's fastest solution.

Here is code, maybe will be useful for someone:

```
<?php

define(APP_CLIENT_ID, '<client_id>');
define(CLIENT_SECRET, '<client_secret>');
define(AD_TENANT_ID, '<tenant_id>');
define(RESOURCE_URL, 'https://rest.media.azure.net');

function curlTokenRequest() {

    $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".AD_TENANT_ID."/oauth2/token";

    $request = "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=".RESOURCE_URL."&client_id=".APP_CLIENT_ID."&client_secret=".CLIENT_SECRET;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,        // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,         // follow redirects
        // CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "utf-8",           // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 200,          // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 200,          // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_POST            => 1,            // i am sending post data
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request,    // this are my post vars
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,            // don't verify ssl
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        //
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        )

    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    //echo $curl_errno;
    //echo $curl_error;
    curl_close($ch);

    http_response_code($httpcode);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    return $data;
}
```